# WPF and Screen Resolution

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application in C#.net. I have a question regarding Window adjustment. In Some Screen Resolutions my main window is OK  but  in wide screen monitor and some other screen resolution window and controls in it are Cluttered.

Comment: Some code and screenshot will be helpful in understanding the problem and giving some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Hi one of the simplest way to do that is do not set the width and Height of window and set the property SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight as

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid Height="226">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you hard code `Height` and `Width` or, align elements only using `margins` you'll run into scaling problems with different resolutions. You need a clever grid layout where you only assign Row and Columns to controls and set their `Horizontal` and `Vertical Alignments`. Thus, even if the grid resizes the relative arrangement of elements will not alter and the layout will remain consistent.
If you don't take advantage of higher resolutions in your application (like displaying more items) you may consider using `Canvas` inside a `ViewBox` which basically Scales to Fit everything.